# Using try catch in various validation

Tags: java

Could you help me with this validation with try catch please?

```
package application;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

import entities.Contract;
import entities.Instatllment;
import services.ContractServices;
import services.PaypalService;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        /*Para ler a data precisa dessa funçao*/
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyy");
        
        
        System.out.println("Entre com o número do contrato: ");
        System.out.print("Numero do contrato: ");
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Data (dd/MM/yyyy)");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(sc.next(),fmt);
        System.out.print("Entre com o valor do contrato: ");
        double totalValue = sc.nextDouble();
        
        Contract obj = new Contract(number, date, totalValue); 
        
        System.out.print("Entre com o número de parcelas: ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        
        ContractServices contractServices = new ContractServices(new PaypalService());
        
        contractServices.processContract(obj, n);
        
        
        System.out.println("____Parcelas______");
        for (Instatllment instatllment : obj.getInstatllment()) {
            System.out.println(instatllment);
        }
        sc.close();

    }
    

}
```

I would like to use "try catch" to validate that all the entries are correct (contract number, date and contract value).

I tried so far and work

```
boolean entradaValida = false;
            int numero = 0;

            while (!entradaValida) {
                System.out.print("Digite um número: ");
                String input = sc.nextLine();

                try {
                    // Tenta converter a entrada para um número inteiro
                    numero = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    entradaValida = true; // Se a conversão for bem-sucedida, saia do loop
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // Se a entrada não puder ser convertida para um número, imprima uma mensagem de erro
                    System.out.println("Por favor, digite um número válido.");
                }
            }
```

But the rest I couldn't
Exemple:

```
boolean entradaValida = false;
            int numero = 0;

            while (!entradaValida) {
                System.out.print("Digite um número: ");
                String input = sc.nextLine();

                try {
                    // Tenta converter a entrada para um número inteiro
                    numero = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    entradaValida = true; // Se a conversão for bem-sucedida, saia do loop
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // Se a entrada não puder ser convertida para um número, imprima uma mensagem de erro
                    System.out.println("Por favor, digite um número válido.");
```

The try I do is to validate the code's data input. I need all inputs to be validated. Example:

```
Catch  (NumberFormatException e){
System.out.print("Data (dd/MM/yyyy)")}:
Catch (DateFromatException e){
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(sc.next(),fmt);
        System.out.print("Entre com o valor do contrato: ");
        double totalValue = sc.nextDouble()};
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you saying that it doesn't work, or that you're not sure whether it works or not and want help testing it?

Comment: The code you posted should work fine. What is your question?

Comment: My question is: in this code, how do I "catch" the date and other questions. Because any value I put differently breaks it.

Comment: Example: 

```System.out.print("Contract date dd/MM/yyyy: ");
LocalDate data = LocalDate.parse(sc.next(),fmt);

System.out.print("Enter the contract value: ");
doubletotalValue = sc.nextDouble();```

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77290808/edit) and/or [change](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77290808/edit) the relevant information to/in the question (comments may be deleted at any time). But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now.

Comment: I'm going comments the question. Is better.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I would like to use "try catch" to validate that all the entries are correct (contract number, date and contract value). ..."*

Try the following.

```java
import static java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO;
import static java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN;
import static java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern;
```

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
boolean exit = false;
BigDecimal number = ZERO, totalValue = ZERO;
String s, date = null;
do {
    System.out.print("Numero do contrato: ");
    s = sc.nextLine();
    try {
        number = new BigDecimal(s);
        exit = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("try again");
    }
} while (!exit);
exit = false;
do {
    System.out.print("Data (dd/MM/yyyy)");
    try {
        LocalDate.parse(date = sc.nextLine(), ofPattern("dd/MM/yyy"));
        exit = true;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("try again");
    }
} while (!exit);
exit = false;
do {
    System.out.print("Entre com o valor do contrato: ");
    s = sc.nextLine();
    try {
        totalValue = new BigDecimal(s).setScale(2, HALF_EVEN);
        exit = true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("try again");
    }
} while (!exit);
```

Output

```
Numero do contrato: abc
try again
Numero do contrato: 123
Data (dd/MM/yyyy)15/10/2023
Entre com o valor do contrato: 123
number = 123
date = 15/10/2023
totalValue = 123.00
```

Comment: Perfect!!!
Thanks!!!